# Spring integration - message store recovery/resend

Tags: spring, jms, integration, activemq-classic, spring-jdbc

I have a question regarding the behavior of a jdbc message store.  I notice that if a failure occurs for instance if the following sequence is followed:
1)inbound-channel-adapter - Creates a message payload and sends it to a channel
2)The channel is polled for the payload by a jms:outbound-channel-adapter which adds an entry in the JMS queue.  I am using ActiveMQ.

When I test for a situation like shutting down the MOM I would like to persist the message in the message-store, but this is not the default behavior.  Looks like SI processes the payload in the channel and then pushes it out (deletes it from the store).  I can see the message being inserted in the message-store in the database.

Am I wrong in understanding the function of a message-store?  I thought that the message would persist until a successful run. Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up durable subscriptions for that. I think most of the SI JMS components do support that.

Comment: thanks. If the broker is down then it will fail irrespective of topic or queue. Anyway, if activemq or any other mom is down then what is the best practice for resending the message?  I thought that messagestore would provide the backing for the channel.

Comment: With pure JMS, a durable subscription is exactly what you're looking for. If messages are send but a consumer subscribed with a durable subscription is offline, the broker will persist the messages and deliver them as soon as the consumer becomes available again. I don't know how to archive this with SI, since some components throw an exception if no consumer is available. SI often makes some easy things hard... If you don't need SI, I would use pure JMS instead (Without spring's JMS-Template! The JMS-API is very simple to use directly.)